# Help creating crosstab query with Access

Tags: ms-access, inner-join, crosstab

I'm trying to make a crosstab query (with access tables), But I got lost writing the inner joins statements.
My end result suppose to be the "QueryResult".

Table1 holds the fund information,
Table2 are the type of data the funds have
Table3 is a conversion from the codes of the data to the type data in table2, and Table4 holds the data.

**Table1**

```
FundID FundName
1      Fund1
2      Fund2
3      Fund3
4      Fund4
5      Fund5
6      Fund6
7      Fund7
```

**Table2**

```
TypeID TypeName
1      Balance
2      Yield
3      Fees
4      Deposits
5      Withdraws
```

**Table3**

```
CodeID TypeID    
KT111   1
KT112   2
KT113   3
KT115   3
KT116   4
KT117   4
KT118   5
KT119   5
```

**Table 4**

```
CodeID FundID DataVal
KT111  1      1000
KT116  2      40
KT118  3      30
KT119  3      30
KT118  2      10
KT119  2      50
KT111  2      3000
KT111  3      2000
KT112  1      1.5
KT112  2      1.0
KT112  3      0.5
```

P.S: Table4 holds much rows then shown here with codes which I do not need.

**QueryResult**

```
FundID  Balance Yield Fees Deposits Withdraws
1        1,000   1.5   555   40     60
2        3,000   1.0   155   20     60
3        2,000   0.5   255   70     60
```

What is the right statement to get the query result? (I got lost on the inner joins...) 
Is there also a way to sum some of the data, and show the value (without summing) of other data from table4?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while I am not exactly sure of all of the requirements you have, this might get you started:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(d.dataval) as DataValue
SELECT d.fundid
FROM 
((Data d
INNER JOIN fund f ON d.fundid = f.fundid)
INNER JOIN  code c ON d.codeid = c.codeid)
INNER JOIN type t on c.typeid = t.typeid
GROUP BY d.fundid
PIVOT T.Typename
```

Results:

```
fundid  Balance Deposits    Withdraws   Yield
1       1000                            1.5
2       3000    40      60      1
3       2000            60      0.5
```

Comment: Hi, thanks I will try it and let you know.
What if I want the fund's name to appear, too?